# How do I move the function **Future<void> fetchData()** to a service class

Tags: flutter, dart

I'd like to restructure my code to **MVVM**, I'm new to flutter, How do I restructure the function above to a **Service Class**
import 'dart:convert';

```
import 'package:amaizi_test/models/UserModel.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class JsonApiPhp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _JsonApiPhpState createState() => _JsonApiPhpState();
}

class _JsonApiPhpState extends State<JsonApiPhp> {

  bool loading = true;
  final String url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users';
  var client = http.Client();
  List<UserModel> users = [];


  @override
  void initState(){
    fetchData();
    super.initState();
  }
```

I'd like to restructure my files,

```
  Future<void> fetchData() async {
    http.Response response = await client.get(Uri.parse(url));
    if(response.statusCode == 200){ // Connection Ok
      List responseJson = json.decode(response.body);
      responseJson.map((m) => users.add(new UserModel.fromJson(m))).toList();
      setState(() {
        loading = false;
      });
    } else {
      throw('error');
    }
  }
```

and inititialize in HomePage InitState

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Container(
        child: loading ?
        Container(
          child: Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          ),
        ) :
        ListView.builder(
          itemCount: users.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
            return Card(
              child: ListTile(
                title: Text(
                  users[index].name,
                ),
              ),
            );
          },
        )
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

// The function calls API and displays in UI

Answer (score 1):

For example you can create directory "services" inside lib dir, then create inside that directory dart file with your service class.
For example:

```
class ServerApiService{
  Future<List<User>> fetchData() async {
    ///your code, but without setState()
    return users;
  }
}
```

After it in initState you can create service object and call your fetchData function from service class. But instead of create service class object every time, I recommend to create service object above MaterialApp and use Provider for access service object in any widget of app.

You can use FutureBuilder widget for access data from fetchData() method.

```
FutureBuilder<List<User>>(
    future: users,
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasData) {
        var data = snapshot.data!;
        return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: data.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              User user = data[index];
              return Card(
                  child: ListTile(
                  title: Text(
                  user.name,
                 ),
                ),
               )
            });
      }
      else if (snapshot.hasError) {
        return Text("${snapshot.error}");
      }
      else {
        return Container(
          child: Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          ),
        );
      }
    });
```

Where users which access FutureBuilder (future: users) is fetchedData from service object.

And also little note: better if inside initState() you will call super.initState() above other code.
Start your initState with super.initState and end your dispose with super.dispose